# Is there a standalone Java library which provides LDAP style parsing?

Tags: java, parsing, filter, ldap

I'm looking for a standalone Java library which allows me to parse LDAP style filter expressions Is such thing available, or is it advisable to use ANTLR instead and build it by one self?

As background: the filter itself is submitted through a network, and I want to create say, the appropriate hibernate Criteria. **I'm not doing anything with LDAP!**

Any other ideas for a technology independent solution to transfer and transform user defined queries are also appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the apache directory server's shared LDAP library.

It is available in maven at

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.directory.shared</groupId>
  <artifactId>shared-ldap</artifactId>
  <version>0.9.15</version>
</dependency>
```

And you can use it like:

```
final ExprNode filter = FilterParser.parse(filterString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also look at using [Apache directory server](http://directory.apache.org/) either for using some of its classes like lavinio's suggestion for OpenLDAP or to embed it as part of your application.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenDS](http://opends.java.net/) has a static method on a class called LDAPFilter called, simply, *decode*, which takes a string argument, like so:

```
LDAPFilter parsed = LDAPFilter.decode(filter);
```

The javadoc is [here](http://java.net/downloads/opends/promoted-builds/2.2.1/javadoc/org/opends/server/protocols/ldap/LDAPFilter.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29).

It's very similar to Apache DS's FilterParser, though working with the result is a little different as there's no real substantial inheritance hierarchy.  One advantage I found was that it didn't rewrite extensible matching rule syntax, so if you're looking at this as a way to validate and normalize filters that's something to keep in mind.

A caveat is that both parsers expect whitespace to be filtered out beforehand, so make sure you run something like this on any input string beforehand:

```
filter.replaceAll("\\s?([\\(\\|&!=:\\)])\\s?", "$1");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The only LDAP parsing library I know of are the .NET ones System.DirectoryServices.*  In theory you should be able to use this library in Mono to get technology independence (other than from mono or .net itself).

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at jldap, as part of OpenLDAP?

The [source is available](http://www.openldap.org/devel/cvsweb.cgi/com/novell/ldap/?cvsroot=JLDAP&hideattic=1&sortbydate=0), and there are classes for parsing both LDAP URLs and *search expressions*.  It's more than you need, but you might be able to use just the objects without actually executing them against an LDAP server, if that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

to clarify, are you set on them being LDAP syle queries, if you're not trying to query ldap.

have you looked at something like this?

http://josql.sourceforge.net/

Comment: interesting, but not what I'm looking for. In one case I query java objects directly, indeed, but I'm also using the same query to construct a SQL or Hibernate Query.

Answer (score 0):

Most OSGi containers also contain this functionality, since [these kinds of filters are part of the OSGi specification](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/framework/Filter.html).