# LDAP search filter expression utility or library

Tags: java, search, ldap, expression

in this project we intend to reuse ldap search expressions for a system other than the LDAP server itself.

The idea is to fetch the expression - something like (|(attr1='A')(!(attr2='1'))) - and perform certain actions. Does anybody know of the existence of a library or utility to interpret such expressions ?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a standalone Java library which provides LDAP style parsing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027307/is-there-a-standalone-java-library-which-provides-ldap-style-parsing)

Answer (score 1):

It's a polish expression, for that you can use [ANTLR 3](http://www.antlr.org/) I think the grammar exists. Parhaps the thing you are looking for is [there](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/directory/shared/shared-ldap/0.9.7/shared-ldap-0.9.7-javadoc.jar!/org/apache/directory/shared/ldap/filter/AntlrFilterParser.html).

Comment: ApacheDS actually [dropped the ANTLR grammar](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/DIRSERVER-986) in the latest version, but it may still be possible to leverage [the newer filter parsing implementation](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/directory/shared/trunk/ldap/model/src/main/java/org/apache/directory/shared/ldap/model/filter/), which is in the [shared-ldap-model](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.directory.shared/shared-ldap-model/1.0.0-M4) jar.

Answer (score 1):

The UnboundID LDAP SDK for Java includes a Filter class that can be used to construct and parse search filter strings like the one you have listed.  The Filter class also provides a matchesEntry method that can be used to determine whether a filter matches a provided entry using only client-side logic.